# When is the esp register set in linux?

Tags: linux

Before a program is executed, when is the `esp` register set to point to a valid address? During the call to `exec`? Or in user space itself? I've gone through the kernel code and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background**

x86 CPUs have two (actually four) stacks (per task): One for the user mode and one for the kernel mode.

When an interrupt occurs in user mode the CPU will set `esp` to the address of the kernel's stack (see "TSS" for more information) and push the original value of `esp` (location of the user mode's stack) to the (kernel's) stack. `eip`, `cs` and `eflags` are always pushed to the stack when an interrupt occurs.

When returning from the interrupt the `iret` instruction will pop the "old" register values from the (kernel's) stack and the stack pointer will point to the user's stack again.

A preemptive multi-tasking operating system typically works the following way:

Some task is running which means that this task takes 100% of the CPU load for a very small amount of time. When a timer interrupt occurs the register values of the currently running task are stored on the stack (by the CPU). The OS will `push` the values of all other registers and change the `esp` value to the kernel stack of another task (which were saved when another timer interrupt happened). Then it `pops` the registers and performs an `iret` so all registers contain the values of another task and the other task is running.

In Linux (4.12.2), x86-32 this is done by the function `__switch_to_asm` in the assembly source "entry_32.S".

**Direct answer to your question**

When a new task is created the two stacks (user and kernel stack) are allocated for that task and the initial register values to be `poped` in the interrupt are written to the kernel stack. This includes the initial value of `esp` for the user mode.

Some timer interrupt later the task is started the first time (the same way an already running task is re-activated).

In (old versions of) Linux there are two commands used to create a new task:

- `fork()` will simply copy the kernel stack. `fork()` will duplicate an existing task so all register values (including `esp`) must be identical to the already existing task
- `execve()` will not allocate a new kernel stack (now new task is created but another executable is being run in the current task). Execve will allocate a new user stack and overwrite the `esp` value on the kernel stack. (Mark Plotnick's comment is showing you the position where this is done.)